# Friends on Facebook can not see my posts

Tags: facebook

I have tried to upload photos on my timeline and none of my friends can see them. Why? Also, some of my friends are not showing on my friends list.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Facebook image]

When uploading images check whether they can be seen by public or not.

Answer (score -1):

May be your account in private mode. Just try it once just upload the image and make it as a public mode and check it now..may be it visible to your friends ...